# create img element with onload function - pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, onload

I'm a beginner to javascript, but want to be able to dynamically create an image element with an onload function (with pure javascript, not with jquery).

I need this for preloading. I know there are many ways to preload images. However, I specifically want to preload the images by dynamically creating them one by one.

What I try to achieve is that once the first img element is loaded, another is created. I hope anyone can explain what is wrong with my code. I know there are many alternatives for preloading, please only be so kind to mention them if it is impossible to preload in this way.

Also, to me it seems logic that onload should be placed after the src, however I've read on other posts that this shouldn't be done. Is the onload at the right place here?

Here is my javscript: http://jsfiddle.net/GB4Hs/1/

```
img_path = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png';

goThrough = 1;
preload();

function preload(){
 if(goThrough == 1){
  goThrough = 0;
  img1 = document.createElement('img');
  img1.onload = function(){goThrough=2;};
  img1.src = img_path;
  img1.style.width = '480px;';
  img1.style.height = '270px;';
  document.body.appendChild(img1);
 };
 if(goThrough == 2){
  goThrough = 0;
  img2 = document.createElement('img');
  img2.onload = function(){goThrough=3;};
  img2.src = img_path;
  img2.style.width = '480px;';
  img2.style.height = '270px;';
  document.body.appendChild(img2);
 }; 
 if(goThrough < 3){
  preload();
 };
};
```

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: What is the result of the above code ?

Comment: You have, in this script running before any page is loaded, " body.appendChild(img);"  who is body? Body should not be defined at the time the script runs. You should be getting a clear error message stating this. (are you?)

Comment: Thank you for correcting me on this dumb mistake! The first image should've loaded properly but didn't due to the mistake stommepoes described. I've added a fiddle to show the result (1 image is created, put in the document, but the load event doesn't trigger the 2nd to be made).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not calling the `preload` function again in the `onload` callbacks.

```
function preload(){
 if(goThrough == 1){
  img1.onload = function(){goThrough=2; preload();};
  // ...
 };
 if(goThrough == 2){
  img2.onload = function(){goThrough=3; preload();};
  // ...
 }; 
 if(goThrough < 3){
  preload();
 };
};
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GB4Hs/2/

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to solve my question. I assumed the triggered event wouldn't bother the rest of the function.